# ¿Cómo enviar los datos ingresados en un formulario a un correo?

Tags: php, javascript, html, formularios

Tengo una página web en la que tengo un formulario de contacto, lo que necesito es que los datos ingresados ​​por el usuario en este formulario me lleguen a mi correo al momento que den clic en enviar ☹ he intentado varias formas que e visto en internet y algunos videos pero no me sale, no logro cumplir con este objetivo, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
if (!$HTTP_POST_VARS){
?>

 <center><form action="envia_form_CONTACTO.php" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" id="formu" name="formu" method="POST">
      <div class="titulo"><center><p><font face="arial black"> QUIERO SER CONSULTOR/A </font></p></center></div>
      <hr>
      <label class="parrafo"><b></b><p class="texto1"><font face="arial" color="black" size="5" class="texto2"> Forma parte de nuestra red de consultores natura.</p>
      <p>Completa tu información y nos pondremos en contacto contigo.</p>
      <p>También puedes comunicarte con nosotros por el correo electrónico: “naturagdl@outlook.es” </p> 
      <p>Ó a los teléfonos: 3317118833 - 5520557517</p><p class="texto3">¡Forma parte de esta gran red!</font></p>

      <hr class="division">
      <br><font face="arial" size="5" color="RED" class="texto4">NOTA:</font></b><font face="arial" color="black" size="5" class="texto5">Toda la información aquí proporcionada será tratada confidencialmente.</font></label>
      <p><hr></p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <center>
      <div class="contenedor_inputs">
      <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="input-nombre" value="" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre completo"><font class="asterisco" color="Red">*</font>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="direccion" name="direccion" class="input-direccion" value="" placeholder="Ingresa tu dirección"><font class="asterisco" color="Red">*</font>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono" class="input-telefono" value="" placeholder="Ingresa tu teléfono"><font class="asterisco" color="Red">*</font>

      <input type="text" id="correo" name="correo" class="input-correo" value="" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo"><font class="asterisco" color="Red">*</font></center>
      <br>
      <br>
      <center><textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" class="input-mensaje" value="" maxlength="500" placeholder="Ingresa un mensaje"></textarea></center>
      <br>
      <br>
<center><input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" class="enviar"></center><br><br><br> 
</div>
    </center></form>
    <?php
    }else{
    $cuerpo = "Formulario enviado\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Nombre: " . $HTTP_POST_VARS["nombre"] . "\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Direccion: " . $HTTP_POST_VARS["direccion"] . "\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Telefono: " . $HTTP_POST_VARS["telefono"] . "\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Correo: " . $HTTP_POST_VARS["correo"] . "\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Comentarios: " . $HTTP_POST_VARS["mensaje"] . "\n";
     mail("ricardog980726@gmail.com","Formulario recibido",$cuerpo);
      echo "Gracias por rellenar el formulario. Se ha enviado correctamente.";
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: Al margen pero debes tener cuidado [con la super global que estás usando](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php) pues esta **obsoleta**, en su lugar **debes** estar aplicando **`$_POST`**

Comment: Este codigo lo estas ejecutando en localhost?

Comment: ¿Revisaste la carpeta SPAM o Correo No Deseado de tu correo electrónico?

Comment: @WilfredoAleman Así es, es correcto.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si ya revisé todas las carpetas en el correo y no hay nada

Comment: Si estás en localhost puede que necesites configurar un servidor smtp en el equipo local y/o indicarlo en el archivo `php.ini`. Hay diversas formas de hacer esto y depende de tu sistema operativo.

Comment: SI lo estas ejecutando desde localhost el correo es imposible que te llegue a tu bandeja ya que no se envía en realidad .

Debes configurar mercury si utilizar xammp  o subir el codigo a tu hosting y probarlo desde ahi

Answer (score 0):

Este sería tu programa funcionando.

Te devolverá un error de la función mail si lo estás ejecutando en un servidor local o en un servidor gratuito, porque tendrán los envíos deshabilitados, pero verás que funciona correctamente. Simplemente era utilizar $_POST porque es la forma actual de enviar los datos.

Un saludo.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['enviar'])){
?>

 <center><form action="prueba.php" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" id="formu" name="formu" method="POST">
      <div class="titulo"><center><p><font face="arial black"> QUIERO SER CONSULTOR/A </font></p></center></div>
      <hr>
      <label class="parrafo"><b></b><p class="texto1"><font face="arial" color="black" size="5" class="texto2"> Forma parte de nuestra red de consultores natura.</p>
      <p>Completa tu información y nos pondremos en contacto contigo.</p>
      <p>También puedes comunicarte con nosotros por el correo electrónico: “naturagdl@outlook.es” </p> 
      <p>Ó a los teléfonos: 3317118833 - 5520557517</p><p class="texto3">¡Forma parte de esta gran red!</font></p>

      <hr class="division">
      <br><font face="arial" size="5" color="RED" class="texto4">NOTA:</font></b><font face="arial" color="black" size="5" class="texto5">Toda la información aquí proporcionada será tratada confidencialmente.</font></label>
      <p><hr></p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <center>
      <div class="contenedor_inputs">
      <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="input-nombre" value="" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre completo"><font class="asterisco" color="Red">*</font>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="direccion" name="direccion" class="input-direccion" value="" placeholder="Ingresa tu dirección"><font class="asterisco" color="Red">*</font>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono" class="input-telefono" value="" placeholder="Ingresa tu teléfono"><font class="asterisco" color="Red">*</font>

      <input type="text" id="correo" name="correo" class="input-correo" value="" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo"><font class="asterisco" color="Red">*</font></center>
      <br>
      <br>
      <center><textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" class="input-mensaje" value="" maxlength="500" placeholder="Ingresa un mensaje"></textarea></center>
      <br>
      <br>
<center><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="ENVIAR" class="enviar"></center><br><br><br> 
</div>
    </center></form>
    <?php
    }else{
    $cuerpo = "Formulario enviado\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Nombre: " . $_POST["nombre"] . "\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Direccion: " . $_POST["direccion"] . "\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Telefono: " . $_POST["telefono"] . "\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Correo: " . $_POST["correo"] . "\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Comentarios: " . $_POST["mensaje"] . "\n";
     mail("ricardog980726@gmail.com","Formulario recibido",$cuerpo);
      echo "Gracias por rellenar el formulario. Se ha enviado correctamente.";
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: Hola que tal, ese código que pusiste al incio "if (!isset($_POST['enviar'])){" lo había puesto anteriormente, pero no me funcionó tampoco, no sé si exista algún otro error o que onda 

Gracias, saludos.

Comment: Buenas Ricardo. Pero, ¿qué problema tienes? ¿qué error te da? Yo he probado ese mismo código y solo me indica que mail no puede enviar el correo, nada más. Si me dices el error te podré ayudar. Un saludo.

Comment: No me sale ningún error, lo corre y todo, pero no manda los datos del formulario al correo, en el correo no me llega nada.
Una vez hecho el código, lo subo al webhost, lo abro ya desde internet y lo lleno el formulario pero no me llega nada al correo electrónico.

Gracias

Comment: ¿El hosting es de pago?, si no lo es entonces no podrás enviar correos porque es una opción que hace unos años han deshabilitado para que los usuarios no hagan envíos masivos.